# More efficient for each loops

Tags: vb.net, optimization, loops, .net-2.0, performance

Is there a more efficient way of doing this code?

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim ts1 As String = row(0).ToString
    For index As Integer = 1 To 9
        Dim colName As String
        colName = dt.Columns(index).ToString
        For Each row2 As DataRow In dtAppAvail.Rows
            Dim colName2 As String
            Dim ts2 As String
            colName2 = row2("Day").ToString.Substring(0, 3) & " " & CType(row2("Date"), Date).ToString("dd/MM")
            ts2 = row2("Timeslot").ToString
            If colName = colName2 AndAlso ts1 = ts2 Then
                row(index) = row2("AppointmentsBooked")
            End If
        Next
    Next                            
Next
```

Comment: Does it work? Is it slow? Is there a reason your looking to improve efficentcy?

Comment: Premature eje.. optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: it is slow because of so many for loops - trying to reduce it so it is more compact?

Comment: I would look into LINQ to solve this without loops.

Comment: I wish I could but using .net 2.0

Comment: If your DataRow is populated by a database, I would suggest you do a specific query the get the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            For index As Integer = 1 To 9
                For Each row2 As DataRow In dtAppAvail.Rows
                    Dim colName2 As String = row2("Day").ToString.Substring(0, 3) & " " & CType(row2("Date"), Date).ToString("dd/MM")
                    If dt.Columns(index).ToString = colName2 AndAlso row(0).ToString = row2("Timeslot").ToString Then
                        row(index) = row2("AppointmentsBooked")
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

Here is a more condensed version...
it uses less variables which i assume = less memory storage, but i doubt you will notice much of a difference...

Answer (score 0):

If your Datatable is huge, then make the loop parallel.
I would have recommended on using `parallel.foreach` which comes with .NET 4, but since you specified .NET 2, you can implement it by yourself.

Check the "Patterns for Parallel Programming":

```
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19222
```